# Android - Crop an image from multipoints

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I need to crop a Bitmap, but instead of having a **rectangular** cropped image (which I managed successfully to do), I need it to be **any form** defined by coordinates.

I'm following the answer from this thread: [Cutting a multipoint ploygon out of Bitmap and placing it on transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993292/cutting-a-multipoint-ploygon-out-of-bitmap-and-placing-it-on-transparency) , and trying to implement it, but unfortunatly it does not clip the image.

I did as in the description, but it seems there's a bug somewhere. The image is drawn in rectangular way. 
Am I missing something?

```
Bitmap originalBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_image);
// Image cropped
Bitmap croppedBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 10, 10, 200, 200);
Canvas canvas=new Canvas(croppedBitmap);

// Create a path
Path path=new Path();
path.setFillType(FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.moveTo(0, 100);
path.moveTo(100, 0);
path.moveTo(0, 0);

// Paint with Xfermode
Paint paint=new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

// Draw the path
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the image will ALWAYS be rectangular.  An image cannot be anything other than a rectangle.  Therefore the best you can do is cut out a polygon and place it on a transparent background.

Comment: I see. Could you please give some directions how I would go about cutting a polygon? Actually this is what I'm trying to do in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was very close to the solution. Here it is:

```
compositeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Bitmap bitmap1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.batman_ad);
Bitmap bitmap2=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);

Bitmap resultingImage=Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, bitmap1.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultingImage);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
Path path=new Path();
path.lineTo(150, 0);
path.lineTo(230, 120);
path.lineTo(70, 120);
path.lineTo(150, 0);

canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);

compositeImageView.setImageBitmap(resultingImage);
```

Comment: Hey! @Andy can you post your crop image code and screens that you have created for crop because i also searching polygon shape crop view.