# Crop image based on X, Y coordinates in java

Tags: java, image, crop

I want to crop my image using 4 XY coordinates in an image. I looked at BufferedImage 's getSubImage method as well however didnt find it useful for my requirement.

Any way to crop it using the  4 coordinates points (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4)

Comment: So why did you not find it useful?

Comment: What the problem with `subImage()`?

Comment: why 4 points? you only need two if i'm not mistaken...

Comment: Yea I figured that out after reading Danstahr answer. My mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rectangle in plane with sides parallel to axes can be characterized by two points : top left `(x1, y1)` and bottom right `(x2, y2)` corners. So just use `getSubImage()` appropriately :

```
/*    
(x1, y1) ....... (w = y2-y1) .. (x2, y1)
 .
 .                                 
 (h = y2-y1)                        
 .
 .
(x1, y2) .......................(x2, y2)  */  

BufferedImage myImaxe;
myImage.getSubImage(x1, y1, (x2-x1), (y2-y1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to 
http://sanjaal.com/java/395/java-graphics/cropping-an-image-in-java-sampletutorial-with-source-code/
for rectangular cropping. Since you have written in your post that you want to crop your image through four x, y co-ordinates I suppose that you want to do non rectangular cropping. Refer to [Android - Crop an image from multipoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579645/android-crop-an-image-from-multipoints/11841619#11841619) or [How to crop an image in between four points on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721111/how-to-crop-an-image-in-between-four-points-on-android) or http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/30097-image-cropping.html

Best of Coding!