# Android Freehand bitmap cropping

Tags: android, bitmap, polygon, crop

I know we can crop a bitmap in rectangular shape using:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height)
```

But I want to know to crop a bitmap in freehand mode or some polygon shape. Its best example can be seen in [Jigsaw Puzzle game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coder.hamster.jpall.cats)

I have spent a lot of time googling about this but found no help. Can anybody help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Path`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) to determine a clip area on your `Canvas` when drawing a `Bitmap`.

For a full example see:

[Android - Crop an image from multipoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579645/android-crop-an-image-from-multipoints)

and also:

[Cutting a multipoint ploygon out of Bitmap and placing it on transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993292/cutting-a-multipoint-ploygon-out-of-bitmap-and-placing-it-on-transparency)